# macOS admin password not working inside terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, active-directory, passwords, root

I'm required at work to use a Mobile Account connected to Active Directory. I also have an Administrator account on my computer (which is a local account).

Whenever I need to use `sudo` commands from the terminal, logged in as **Mobile Account**, the **password of the Admin account** is never recognized. 
All the other operations that need a password input (e.g. the authorization to install Applications) work, so I can't explain why inside the terminal it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by putting my user in the list of `sudoers`.

[Checkout this link on how to do it](https://manik.me/2017/05/26/add-user-sudoers-file-mac-os-x/).